# Why was the question 'Kaaba of Mecca and the Hindu connection' migrated to History SE?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, migration

*[Kaaba of Mecca and The Hindu connection?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/kaaba-of-mecca-and-the-hindu-connection?noredirect=1)* on Hinduism SE was migrated to History SE ([Was Kaaba initially a Shiva temple?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62822/was-kaaba-initially-a-shiva-temple)) yesterday with this reason:

> This question was migrated to History Stack Exchange because it can be answered by historians and history buffs. Migrated yesterday by Catija♦.

Shouldn't the question be closed as off-topic by *this* community before migrating it to the other site?

Comment: Not sure whether that is the process to follow but even deleted posts are migrated there. which I find strange.

Comment: oh they were deleted yesterday by the mods.

Answer (score 5):

The question has been migrated to History Stack Exchange because it deals with historical proofs and archeological surveys which would fit well and be answered at History Stack Exchange.

Migration happened after mutual accordance between mods of both sites. Because the question was [too old to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/260388), we had asked a CM to accomplish the task and hence the migration task is carried out by CM.

Comment: 'Migration happened after mutual accordance between mods of both sites.' - don't rest of the community have a say on these migrations? Are all history-related questions (e.g., [Did Jesus visit Jagannath Temple of Puri?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/did-jesus-visit-jagannath-temple-of-puri)) being migrated from this site to History SE by mods? What is the exact criteria for migration?